# why do spark MLLIB uses different data format for different classification

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

For example:

1.decision tree algorithm uses following format.

```
1,17.99,10.38,122.8,1001,0.1184,0.2776,0.3001,0.1471,0.2419,0.07871,1.095,0.9053,8.589,153.4,0.006399,0.04904,0.05373,0.01587,0.03003,0.006193,25.38,17.33,184.6,2019,0.1622,0.6656,0.7119,0.2654,0.4601
1,20.57,17.77,132.9,1326,0.08474,0.07864,0.0869,0.07017,0.1812,0.05667,0.5435,0.7339,3.398,74.08,0.005225,0.01308,0.0186,0.0134,0.01389,0.003532,24.99,23.41,158.8,1956,0.1238,0.1866,0.2416,0.186,0.275
1,19.69,21.25,130,1203,0.1096,0.1599,0.1974,0.1279,0.2069,0.05999,0.7456,0.7869,4.585,94.03,0.00615,0.04006,0.03832,0.02058,0.0225,0.004571,23.57,25.53,152.5,1709,0.1444,0.4245,0.4504,0.243,0.3613
1,11.42,20.38,77.58,386.1,0.1425,0.2839,0.2414,0.1052,0.2597,0.09744,0.4956,1.156,3.445,27.23,0.00911,0.07458,0.05661,0.01867,0.05963,0.009208,14.91,26.5,98.87,567.7,0.2098,0.8663,0.6869,0.2575,0.6638
1,20.29,14.34,135.1,1297,0.1003,0.1328,0.198,0.1043,0.1809,0.05883,0.7572,0.7813,5.438,94.44,0.01149,0.02461,0.05688,0.01885,0.01756,0.005115,22.54,16.67,152.2,1575,0.1374,0.205,0.4,0.1625,0.2364
```

2. Binary Classification uses following format.

0 155:53 156:255 157:253 158:253 159:253 160:124 183:180 184:253 185:251 186:251 187:251 188:251 189:145 190:62 209:32 210:217 211:241 212:253 213:251 214:251 215:251 216:251 217:253 218:107 237:37 238:251 239:251 240:253 241:251 242:251 243:251 244:251 245:253 246:107 265:166 266:251 267:251 268:253 269:251 270:96 271:148 272:251 273:253 274:107 291:73 292:253 293:253 294:253 295:253 296:130 299:110 300:253 301:255 302:108 319:73 320:251 321:251 322:251 323:251 327:109 328:251 329:253 330:107 347:202 348:251 349:251 350:251 351:225 354:6 355:129 356:251 357:253 358:107 375:150 376:251 377:251 378:251 379:71 382:115 383:251 384:251 385:253 386:107 403:253 404:251 405:251 406:173 407:20 410:217 411:251 412:251 413:253 414:107 430:182 431:255 432:253 433:216 438:218 439:253 440:253 441:182 457:63 458:221 459:253 460:251 461:215 465:84 466:236 467:251 468:251 469:77 485:109 486:251 487:253 488:251 489:215 492:11 493:160 494:251 495:251 496:96 513:109 514:251 515:253 516:251 517:137 520:150 521:251 522:251 523:251 524:71 541:109 542:251 543:253 544:251 545:35 547:130 548:253 549:251 550:251 551:173 552:20 569:110 570:253 571:255 572:253 573:98 574:150 575:253 576:255 577:253 578:164 597:109 598:251 599:253 600:251 601:251 602:251 603:251 604:253 605:251 606:35 625:93 626:241 627:253 628:251 629:251 630:251 631:251 632:216 633:112 634:5 654:103 655:253 656:251 657:251 658:251 659:251 683:124 684:251 685:225 686:71 687:71

0 128:73 129:253 130:227 131:73 132:21 156:73 157:251 158:251 159:251 160:174 182:16 183:166 184:228 185:251 186:251 187:251 188:122 210:62 211:220 212:253 213:251 214:251 215:251 216:251 217:79 238:79 239:231 240:253 241:251 242:251 243:251 244:251 245:232 246:77 264:145 265:253 266:253 267:253 268:255 269:253 270:253 271:253 272:253 273:255 274:108 292:144 293:251 294:251 295:251 296:253 297:168 298:107 299:169 300:251 301:253 302:189 303:20 318:27 319:89 320:236 321:251 322:235 323:215 324:164 325:15 326:6 327:129 328:251 329:253 330:251 331:35 345:47 346:211 347:253 348:251 349:251 350:142 354:37 355:251 356:251 357:253 358:251 359:35 373:109 374:251 375:253 376:251 377:251 378:142 382:11 383:148 384:251 385:253 386:251 387:164 400:11 401:150 402:253 403:255 404:211 405:25 410:11 411:150 412:253 413:255 414:211 415:25 428:140 429:251 430:251 431:253 432:107 438:37 439:251 440:251 441:211 442:46 456:190 457:251 458:251 459:253 460:128 461:5 466:37 467:251 468:251 469:51 484:115 485:251 486:251 487:253 488:188 489:20 492:32 493:109 494:129 495:251 496:173 497:103 512:217 513:251 514:251 515:201 516:30 520:73 521:251 522:251 523:251 524:71 540:166 541:253 542:253 543:255 544:149 545:73 546:150 547:253 548:255 549:253 550:253 551:143 568:140 569:251 570:251 571:253 572:251 573:251 574:251 575:251 576:253 577:251 578:230 579:61 596:190 597:251 598:251 599:253 600:251 601:251 602:251 603:251 604:242 605:215 606:55 624:21 625:189 626:251 627:253 628:251 629:251 630:251 631:173 632:103 653:31 654:200 655:253 656:251 657:96 658:71 659:20

How can I use first format for all the cases.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have everything using the same data format. This is what LabeledPoint is for, so both classification and regression problems use the same data structure. More details here:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html#labeled-point

The idea behind LabeledPoint is simple you have the label variable and the Vector which could be sparse or dense of the features, as in any classification or regression problem.